# Read File: fscanf doesn't read whitespaces?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem fetching lines from File Pointer using fscanf.

Let's say a want to fetch a line like this:

```
<123324><sport><DESCfddR><spor ds>
```

Fscanf fetch only this part:

```
<123324><sport><DESCfddR><spor
```

Does anybody know how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fscanf` is a function. The format specifiers are responsible for reading.

Comment: There are zillions of different ways to use `fscanf`. `fscanf` is not just a function, it is a small programming language inside C programming language. How are you using it??? Where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conclusion,the best way to read lines which contain whitespaces is to use fgets:

```
fgets (currentLine, MAX_LENGTH , filePointer);
```

Using **fscanf** you are going to mess with a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `%s` in the `fscanf` to read data. From the C11 standard,

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 12. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>     [...]
>     s  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters. <sup>286</sup>
>     [...]

So, `%s` will stop scanning when it encounters a whitespace character or, if the length field is present, until the specified length or until a whitespace character, whichever occurs first.

How to fix this problem? Use a different format specifier:

```
fscanf(fp ," %[^\n]", buffer);
```

The above `fscanf` skips all whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character(space at the start) and then, `%[^\n]` scans everything until a `\n` character.

You can further improve security by using

```
fscanf(fp ," %M[^\n]", buffer);
```

Replace `M` with the size of `buffer` minus one(One space reserved for the NUL-terminator). It is the length modifier. Also checking the return value of `fscanf` is a good idea.

Using `fgets()` is a better way though.